# a way to dismiss the notice flash message in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

is there a way to dismiss the standard rails 3.2 forum notice when created a record or logged in with devise? like in twitter-bootstrap there's a cross you can click to dismiss the notice message.

I hope there is a similar way in standard forms.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You asked if there was a simpler way. There is no built in way to do this.... You will need to do something like this:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <p class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end %>
<% if flash[:error] %>
  <p class="error"><%= flash[:error] %></p>
<% end %>
```

In your app/assets/javascripts/flash.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $(".notice, .error").on("click", (event)->
    $(event.target).hide("slow")
  )
```

This will make it where if you click on the .notice or .error, it will hide the slowly (fade out). To this you can include a X icon to close it.

Comment: The code @Jesse Wolgamott is presented as the modern Rails way and is comparable to what you would in the Twitter bootstrap. Here is a link to the Twitter bootstrap equivalent: http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/alerts-and-errors-tutorial.php  If this is not simple enough, please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you not want notice on any particular action so delete <%= notice%> from application.rb file from your layout folder in view.

I hope i understood your question correctly.

Comment: no actually i want to dismiss the notice when it's showing. so that you can click on it or something so it will dissapear

Comment: ok...put notice in one div and on click make this div's display:none.

Comment: i think that is a javascript option?

Comment: that an option but you sure there isn't a simplier way?

Comment: You need to do it with javascript look this link http://bjhess.com/blog/fading_flash_message/ 
it help's.